# Using CSV file as a stream resource in MOA

Tags: machine-learning, streaming, data-mining, moa

how can I use a csv file as source of stream in MOA?
In the GUI of MOA, there is only some options to use generators. Can I use my own data which is stored in csv file to be a source of streaming?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [SimpleCSVStream](https://github.com/Waikato/moa/blob/master/moa/src/main/java/moa/streams/clustering/SimpleCSVStream.java) class like this:

```java
        SimpleCSVStream stream = new SimpleCSVStream();
        stream.csvFileOption.setValue("d:\\your_filename.csv");
        stream.classIndexOption.setValue(true); //last column is class lable 
        stream.prepareForUse();
        while (stream.hasMoreInstances()) {
            InstanceExample trainInst = stream.nextInstance();

            //learning code
        }
```

Comment: If you are using the **stream clustering algorithms**, you have to get the `Instance` from the `InstanceExample` to make them work. This is done by typing  the following _before the learning code_: `DenseInstance inst = (DenseInstance) trainInst.instance;`. Then, you send that instance to the algorithm, like this: `withDBSCAN.trainOnInstanceImpl(inst);`. Just wanted to mention that, I do not know if the same happens with the classifiers, bc I have not used them. Hope this helps someone :)